# Using Haskell for real-time audio streaming

Tags: linux, haskell, audio, stream, conduit

I would like to be able to play simple[1] audio in realtime from GHCI, starting and stopping independent oscillators and samples ("voices").

Using Bash on Linux, it's easy[2] to [pipe data into a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13732/generating-random-noise-for-fun-in-dev-snd) that streams audio through your speakers.

In Haskell, I imagine something along these lines:

```
x <- realtimeAudioSink
createVoices x [VoiceName "sinewave",VoiceName "drums"]
play x (VoiceName "sinewave") $ sinewave (Hz 440)
play x (VoiceName "sinewave") $ sinewave (Hz 220)
  -- replace the earlier sinewave with a lower-frequency one
play x (VoiceName "drums")
  $ asSoonAs (theTime >= floor theTime)
  $ every (Seconds 10) $ soundfile "snare.wav"
  -- starting on the next second, play the snare drum sample every 10 seconds
destroyVoice x (VoiceName "drums")
  -- the drums stop, the sinewave keeps going
```

Haskell offers a lot of streaming libraries. Each looks hard to learn. Moreover the audio streaming problem is complicated by the need for realtime operation at a specific sample rate, and by the buffering problem[3].

Is this easy or hard?

---

[1] Four sinewaves and four samples concurrently seems like enough bandwidth to explore for a lifetime.

[2] If you use ALSA, for instance, `cat /dev/urandom | aplay` will play white noise. (Warning: It plays at maximum volume.)

[3] The buffering problem arises, I believe, from the following pair of opposing constraints:  (1) If each sample is given its own calculate-and-stream cycle, it might overwhelm the processor. (Or maybe it wouldn't, if the generated audio is simple enough?)  (2) If you calculate too many samples at a time before sending them out, you might not have finished calculating them all in time.

Comment: i would suggest you to look into outputting a binary stream on stdout and then pipe it into aplay like above. basicly smth like this should be passible `haskell-app | aplay`

Comment: How much Haskell do you know?  As it stands this question is too broad.

Comment: I think that library does NOT connect with the outside world, but its [other siblings](https://github.com/mtolly/conduit-audio) do. Check out the other packages.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Is it specific enough now? Regarding myself, I know enough Haskell to have [overhauled the Tidal music-making DSL](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/Tidal/tree/epic/). I'm good inside Haskell, but connecting it to other stuff always confounds me.